# Performance and Ressource usage of two Forms vs. one Form with switch case

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I am programming a simple pacman game without ghosts. So only a symbol as player, some walls and items.

Now I want to have the choice whether to play the game by arrow keys myself, or solve it automatically.
The Form of the user played game is complete.
Now should I create a new Form (with same code for `Paint` Event and `Load` Event) and change only the things that have to be changed, or should I decide via switch case to put all the code together to one Form?

I catch the dircetion via PreviewKeyDown Event and save it to the string variable "direction". Then starting a Timer to slow down the general movement speed of the player.

```
 private void Game_Form_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        //Unterscheide nach Richtung und kontrolliere ob in dieser Richtung Wand ist
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {

            case Keys.Up:
                if (maze[pos_player_index.Item1, pos_player_index.Item2 - 1] == '#')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    key = "up";
                }
                break;
           .
           . 
           .
            }
        //Starte Timer Bewegungsgeschwindigkeit t_move
        t_move.Start();
    }
```

Then in the OnTickEvent I decide what to do with the symbol of the player and check whether there is a wall or not. Then i call Refresh for the player.
the maze itself is only in the global paint event and so it is drawn only once.

void t_move_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Unterscheiden der Richtung durch Hilfsvariable (exemplarisches Kommentieren einer Möglichkeit)
            switch (key)
            {

```
            case "up":
                    //Setzen des neuen Index
                    pos_player_index = new Tuple<int, int>(pos_player_index.Item1, pos_player_index.Item2 - 1);
                    //Überschreiben des Zeichens im Labyrinth durch Leerzeichen -> aufgesammelt
                    maze[pos_player_index.Item1, pos_player_index.Item2] = ' ';
                    //Neuzeichnen der Spielfigur
                    p_player.Refresh();
                    break;
```

So code for graphics and for control is strictly differed.

Comment: It is definitely a bad idea to copy-paste **any** code blocks.

Comment: Could you please add some code? The answer highly depends on how you designed your code. If you consequently separated the code for displaying the game from the code for controlling the game, you can use your form for both scenarios, because it should not matter if the command for "move left" comes in by user action or by your code for automatic solving. [EDIT]: And I don't think your question is related to the "performance"-tag (unless you refer to your performance as developer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, duplicating code is a bad idea - all of a sudden you will have to implement *all changes twice*.

There are many ways to separate functionality in a program.

Currently the *easiest* way is to make your current form an `abstract class PacmanForm` that performs the "shared" functionality, and have a `class UserPacmanForm : PacmanForm` and a `class RobotPacmanForm : PacmanForm`.

**However** I don't think the winforms designer likes abstract classes that much. If you want to be able to use the designer, **create a backup** of your project before trying.

An alternative is to move the common code to a separate `PacmanGame` class, that for instance has the following methods:

- A constructor, probably the code you currently have in your `Form.Load` event handler
- A `Render(Graphics g)` method which renders the game
- A `Move(Direction d)` method, which handles movement

You can then create two separate forms which both use a `PacmanGame` instance.

PS. I did not focus on performance in my answer, because performance is not an issue here. The bottleneck will most probably be the code that paints the game.